# Which VPN do I use for a Cisco VPN concentrator?

Tags: sync, exchange, vpn

I want to setup corporate sync on my DroidX and it appears to work until I try to get email.

My office uses Microsoft Exchange.

I think I need to set up VPN to do this? (not sure, I know I have to use vpn to make outlook work if I'm not on the network)

Which VPN selection should I use? We are using a really old Cisco VPN concentrator that I don't know much about, with a Microsoft shop for pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android** doesn't natively support pure IPSec client to connect to Cisco like VPN concentrators. For that first you need to root your device and install any custom rom with tun kernel module support and install this app http://code.google.com/p/get-a-robot-vpnc/

Configuration to be used is,

> **Connection Name** : Cisco  (Can be
>   Anything)
>
> **IP Sec Gateway**  : Get it from VPN
>   profile config file [*.pcf]
>
> **IP Sec ID**       : This is the
>   GroupName, can found in pcf file
>
> **IP Sec Secret**   : Decrypted Group
>   password ( Encrypted password can be
>   found in pcf file)
>
> [Decryption Tool](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/bin/cisco-decode)
>
> **UserName**        : VPN User id
>
> **Password**        : Soft token generated
>   password.
>
> Leave all other configuration as empty
>   or default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a "really old" Cisco VPN concentrator, there are pretty good odds that you can get by with a PPTP tunnel. Especially if you're relying on the native Windows client from desktop/laptops (XP?).

However, with Exchange in the mix you may not need to establish a VPN. My new employer runs exchange and I'm using the "Mail" app to connect to it with no fuss or muss. It "just worked" after I plugged in the external mail server address (mail.mycompany.com) and my domain creds.

Comment: OK so maybe really old wasn't a good descriptor :). The Client we use is a cisco vpn client where the copyright ran out in 2006 (version 5.0.00.0340) :). It runs on Windows 7 32 bit no problem but 64 bit causes issues and you need a new client. So all that said, the corporate sync seemed to work with everything but the mail... I'll try using the mail app and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know what concentrator we use I just know cisco has stopped supporting it...

Comment: OK. So, the mail app worked. I can get messages this way, but I kind of wanted to use corporate sync... I guess I need to talk to my network guy?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm using the "Email" app (as opposed to "Mail app" that I said in my original response).

Comment: Hmm. Yeah the Email app won't sync even with the mail.mycompany.com as the server... The weird thing is it synced some of my outlook contacts...